# ObservableObject no actualiza mi variable swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

Me encuentro con un error no se actualizan los datos entre clases y me gustaría hacer una vista dinámica, con una validación pero le e revisado con algunas formas y no la encuentro,

actualmente el código lo tengo así:

> struct PageSocialView: View {
>
> @ObservedObject var visible = MyVariables()
>
> var body: some View {
>
> ZStack{
>
> if (self.visible.cambio == true){
>
> MapaUserView()
>
> }
>
> else{
>
> Color.blue
>
> .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
>
> VStack{
>
> HStack {
>
> login().frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
>
> .padding(.top,100)
>
> }
>
> .cornerRadius(10)
>
> }
>
> }
>
> ---
>
> mi clase con mis variables la tengo así:
>
> class MyVariables: ObservableObject {
>
> @Published var cambio = false
>
> init(){
>
> Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:1.0, repeats: true){(timer)in
>
> self.cambio = self.cambio
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }
>
> ---
>
> y mi clase a actualizar el valor es esta
>
> class Coordinator : NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate{
>
> @ObservedObject var num = MyVariables()
>
> func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result:
>   LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
>
> if error != nil{
>
> print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
>
> }
>
> if AccessToken.current != nil{
>
> let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken:
>   AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
>
> Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential){
>
> (res, er) in
>
> if er != nil{
>
> print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
>
> return
>
> }
>
> print("Pasoooo")
>
> self.num.cambio = true
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }

espero su amable ayuda y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cual es el dato que no se actualiza? Puedes identar y formatear tu código? No se entiende

Answer (score 0):

Primero, las clases `ObservableObject` solo son para uso en `struct` que son una SwiftUI `View` no van a funcionar correctamente en `class Coordinator : NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate`

Segundo, esta `@ObservedObject var visible = MyVariables()` es una forma incorrecta de inicializar un `ObservableObject` debes usar `@StateObject` cuando lo haces así. `@ObservedObject` se usa cuando viene de una `struct` or `class` anterior.

Tercera y mas importante cada vez que llamas esto `MyVariables()` estas creando un nuevo objeto. Que no sabe nada de los otros objetos.

Entonces `MyVariables()` de `PageSocialView` no sabe nada de `MyVariables()` en `Coordinator`.

Tienes q hacer una connection entre una original

```
@StateObject var visible = MyVariables()
```

y los demás usos via

```
@ObservedObject var visible : MyVariables
```

o

```
@EnvironmentObject var visible : MyVariables
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app